# Style Google dictionary API results

Tags: dictionary

I have no idea what I am doing, but I keep trying. I have been trying to find a way to add a dictionary search box to my school website for my 3rd grade (7-8 year olds). Most of the dictionary sites are too complex and riddled with inappropriate advertisements. I found out about google/dictionary.com the other day and have been trying to figure out how to create a custom search with it.

I asked for help here before and was able to get a script that passed a word to the dictionary and displayed the results in an Iframe. Which works ok but it is a full page and I can't change the size of the page in the Iframe.

I came across this

```
http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=dict_api.callbacks.id100&q=school&sl=en&tl=en&restrict=pr%2Cde&client=te
```

Where "school" is the word that is looked up.

However I can't figure out how to style the results, any ideas?

Comment: Could you tell us what language (eg Javascript) you would like a solution in?

Comment: I really can't offer an educated answer to that. I am at square one here. Maybe point me in the right direction.

Comment: Even i am using this url to get the word definition but i am getting the result as JSONP.
Also when used this url with cURL i get the following error: get_definition({},2,"Invalid query: ") where "get_definition" is my callback function. is there something wrong with the url: http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=get_definition&q=school&sl=en&tl=en&restrict=pr%2Cde&client=te

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you dont use this url(API) as it is against google policy. It violates the contract google has with its providers, google asked a developer who made a dictionary extension for chrome to stop using the api.

Comment: Also see: http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/12/on-googles-unofficial-dictionary-api.html

Answer (score 1):

The result is coming back in [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). You'll probably want something that can parse JSON, and then you can output the result in whatever form you like, based on the data from the result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be a little conversant with javascript since the results are sent back as a javascript object ie the result is sent back as json text which you need to parse to retrieve the contents. To parse the contents you can use the javascript eval() function.